# A number theory contest problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

I have come across a problem I can't solve. Can anyone help? Here is the problem
  Find least integer $N$ such that sum of the digits of both $N$ and $N+1$ is divisible by $7$.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews  Thanks for quick reply.  Source of problem is https://pvthuan.files.wordpress.com/2012/03/apmops_mocktest2.pdf  See problem 30

Comment: Apart from the problem 30 , I am stuck with few more problems.  They are problem 17 , 20 , 21,22,24 and 28. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly $N$ must have a $9$ in its ones place or else the sum of digits from $N$ and from $N+1$ will differ by exactly $1$, and therefore could not both be divisible by $7$.

Now when $d_k\cdots d_29$ has $1$ added to it, you maybe get $d_k\cdots (d_2+1)0$ if there is no carrying into the hundreds place. But this $N$ and $N+1$ have digits summing to values that differ by $8$.

So you want some $N$ of the form $d_k\cdots d_399$. But now with $N+1=d_k\cdots (d_3+1)00$ you have digit sums differing by $17$, which is not divisible by $7$.

Adding $1$ to $N$, if the carrying continues all the way to the $10^k$ place, then the difference between the sum of $N$'s digits and the sum of $N+1$'s digits will be $9k-1$. This is first divisible by $7$ when $k=4$. So the number $N$ must be of the form $d_59999$ with $N+1=(d_5+1)0000$. The smallest such example would have the latter number be $70000$, so $N$ is $69999$.